# How to edit the pages on your domain on Godaddy?

Tags: web-hosting, domains, website-design, godaddy

I bought a domain from godaddy.com and I was wondering how to I edit the information on the webpage? Like html FTP and such. And sorry if this isn't on the correct stack website, but this seems like it would be the best to post this question on.

Comment: Have you buy the hosting? If you havent bought their hosting, you cant get information about FTP and other. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't bought hosting then you need to. Assuming you have here's the [Godaddy guide to getting started](http://community.godaddy.com/help/article/1361).